# Isolating $k$ in $H_k=\frac{c}{k+1}$

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I am trying to find an equilibrium point of two algorithms, parametrized by $k$. The performance of the two algorithms:

- $\frac{c}{k+1}$ (where $c$ is some given positive constant)
- $H_k$ (the $k$-th harmonic number)

I am looking for a value $k$ such that $H_k=\frac{c}{k+1}$. I was able find a relatively close approximation using *product-log* ([Lambert **W** function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)). Set $k=e^{W(c)}-1$. This yields (using $e^{W(x)}=\frac{x}{W(x)}$):

- $\frac{c}{k+1}=\frac{c}{e^{W(c)}-1+1}=\frac{c}{e^{W(c)}}=\frac{c}{\frac{c}{W(c)}}=W(c)$
- $H_k=H_{e^{W(c)}-1}\approx\ln(e^{W(c)}-1)+ 1\approx W(c) + 1$

I wonder if there is a way to reach an exact solution, or, to have a solution that minimizes the difference between the two expressions.

Comment: Since an integer value of $k$ probably won't exist in general, I guess you want to regard $k$ as a continuous parameter in order to get an exact solution.  Then how do you define $H_k$?

Comment: That's a good point. The desired goal is, in fact, an integer $k$ that minimizes the difference. I assumed it's too hard to an integer solution so I was hoping to get an approximation based on the real value of $k$. For continues values, I think $H_k$ can be defined as $\psi(k+1)+\gamma$ where $\psi$ is the Polygamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascherani constant.